# Sensitive question on the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

I'm asking a sensitive question.

Suppose, you are a student who is taking an exam on linear algebra. Suppose you're encountering a question asking you to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$. Such problem is stated as below:

> Q: Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for
>   $\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, after some computation, you gain the eigenvalues are $-1,~4$. Next you wish to get the eigenvectors.

For $\lambda=-1:$ we are going to solve the linear system $\begin{bmatrix}3+1&2\\2&0+1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}$.

However, what should the range of $t$ be here? Of course by definition we can't take $t=0$. But what is the exact range we should write?

$\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$?

Or $\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\})$?

Or $\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})\setminus\{0\})$

Comment: Sensitive? The eigenspace is $$\left\{t\pmatrix{-1\\2}:t\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why do you think it should not be $\left\{t\pmatrix{-1\\2}:t\in\Bbb C\right\}.$?

Comment: Your question asked for the **eigenspace**. An eigenspace is a set of vectors....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, I see your point...  But the really point I'm actually asking is the issue of whether the eigenspace/eigenvectors should consists of broadly as $\Bbb C^n$-vectors, or $\Bbb R^n$-vectors.

Comment: Anyway, now I edit the original word eigenspace to eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ are the vectors of the type $(-t,2t)$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. But the eigenspace which corresponds to the eigenvalue $-1$ is$$\left\{(-t,2t)\,\middle|\,t\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$Of course, in the general case we should replace $\mathbb R$ with the field $F$ that we're working with.

Comment: Where justify that this answer should not be $\left\{(-t,2t)\,\middle|\,t\in\mathbb C\right\}$?

Comment: @Eric I have added another sentence to my answer. The field that we're working with should be part of the question.

Comment: I think so! But many exercise or test doesn't clearly specify what the field we're concerning... If $A$ has any of imaginary entry, then it is more explicit. But if $A$ is a real matrix, the things going to be quite ambiguous. For example, $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is diagonalizable in the $\Bbb C$ sense, but not $\Bbb R$ sense. But what if a T/F question just asking whether $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @Eric Believe me: my Linear Algebra students have never been able to find a single exercise proposed by me in which the base field is not clearly stated.

Comment: @Eric Concerning the question from your last comment: without stating somewhere what the base field is, the assertion is neither true nor false.

Comment: I see. So the field which the matrix is over should always be clearly stated by the book authors or exam maker. Even if he had clearly write the entries of the matrix down (just like the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ in my post), the field still requires to be clearly specified.

Comment: @Eric That's right.

Comment: I try to restate a clearer version of the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors for matrices. Can you help me check? Let $E,~F$ be two fields, and $F\leq E$. Let $A\in M_{n}(F)$, $\lambda \in E$. (i) If $\exists v\in E^n\setminus\{0\},~Av=\lambda v$, then $\lambda$ is called *an eigenvalue of $A$ over $E$*. (ii) Let $v\in E^n\setminus\{0\}$. If $Av=\lambda v$, then $v$ is called *an eigenvector of $A$ over $E$ corresponding to $\lambda$*.

Comment: @Eric This is another question. Please post it as such.

Comment: I see. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624882/my-own-version-definition-of-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-for-matrices).

Answer (score 1):

You used the argument that $A∈M_n(\Bbb R)$, so you're talking about a linear mapping of the form $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$. The eigenspace being a sub-space of the co-domain, you clearly need $t \in \Bbb R$. If we were dealing with a co-domain of vectors over $\Bbb C$, your argument would be valid. Keep in mind we're working with $M_n(\Bbb R)$ rather than $M_n(\Bbb C)$ or $M_n(\Bbb C, \Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ya, but any matrix that is "$\in M_n(\Bbb R)$" is inevitably, necessarily, also "$\in M_n(\Bbb C)$". Like the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$ I proposed, 
 in fact $\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ as well. So this arises the annoying ambiguous problems..

Comment: If that's true then anything in $\Bbb R^3$ is in $\Bbb R^{42}$ and then we should have an eigenvetor for an endomorphism over $\Bbb R^3$ that can belong to $\Bbb R^{42}$. See my point? If your co-domain is $\Bbb R^n$, the eigenspace has to be a subspace of that.

Comment: Wait, form what I learnt, $\Bbb R^3$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^{42}$

Comment: It is a subspace and a subset. You compose any vector of $\Bbb R^3$ by combining 3 independent vectors of $\Bbb R^{42}$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the field $F$ you're working over...
You get all scalar multiples  $t \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ for $t\in F\setminus \{0\}$...