# My own version of definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors for matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

Having arise a question on the [ambiguity on the definition of eigenvalues/eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624759/sensitive-question-on-the-definition-of-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors/2624764#2624764). I try to restate a clearer version of the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors for *matrices*, which is aimed at eliminating the annoying ambigouity. I want to ask that is such definition proper, and broader, and clearer?

Let $E,~F$ be two fields, and $F\leq E$. Let $A\in M_{n}(F)$, $\lambda \in E$.

(i) If $(\exists v\in E^n\setminus\{0\},~Av=\lambda v)$, then $\lambda$ is called *an eigenvalue of $A$ over $E$*.

(ii) Let $v\in E^n\setminus\{0\}$. If $Av=\lambda v$, then $v$ is called *an eigenvector of $A$ over $E$ corresponding to $\lambda$*.

PS: Notice the use of extension field and the critical preposition "*over*".

Following such definition, we say:

- $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has no eigenvalues over $\Bbb R$. It also has no eigenvectors over $\Bbb R$.
- $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $i,~-i$ over $\Bbb C$. It also has eigenvectors $\begin{cases}x=it\\y=t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb C-\{0\})$ over $\Bbb C$ corresponding to $i$, and $\begin{cases}x=-it\\y=t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb C-\{0\})$ corresponding to $-i$.
- $\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $-1,~4$ over $\Bbb Q$.  It also has eigenvectors $\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb Q)$ over $\Bbb Q$ corresponding to $-1$.
- $\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $-1,~4$ over $\Bbb C$.  It also has eigenvectors $\begin{cases}x=-t\\y=2t\end{cases}(t\in\Bbb C)$ over $\Bbb C$ corresponding to $-1$.

Comment: There's nothing ambiguous with the usual, standard definition. Clear as water. You don't need two or more fields for the definition as that would add ambiguity...

Comment: Why do you mention two fields $E$ and $F$ and then only write about the field $E$?

Comment: He mention it in $M_n(F)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do this because I want to let people say "Let $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$" and discuss eigen-matters over a possibly bigger field, say $\Bbb C$, and so on.

Comment: @dEmigOd You are right. I failed to notice that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But I feel you're right.., is it as good as just using one field $F$ in the definition?

Comment: @Eric That's what I think.

Comment: @DonAntonio I saw the traditional definition in the books not mentioning over what field explicitly.

Comment: @Eric Exactly: it is **always** over the definition field of the matrix... unless it is allowed, say, to take extension of fields. But this always comes later.

Comment: The problem is not the definition of eigenvalue/eigenvector; the problem is that many texts on linear algebra work steadily over the reals, and then need a side step to the complex numbers when eigenthings appear, and it is quietly assumed that now our matrices are over $\mathbb{C}$. For a beginner, this is a non-trivial step and glossing over it does not help.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Yes.. it is very painful for me when jumping to being over $\mathbb{C}$. It is not being over $\Bbb C$ makes things difficult, but rather some "quiet assumption" and I'm always afraid which things (theorems)  are still available when over $\Bbb C$ and which are not. I trust that beginning with the general setting, i.e. saying "over $F$" at the every beginning of the books is more brilliant, pedagogically speaking.

Comment: I think you should only use one field in the definition. You just have to realize that a real matrix may have no real eigenvalues, or a rational matrix may have no rational eigenvalues. Also if a matrix is defined over a field, we can view it as a matrix over an extension field. It is the extension process which is not treated in enough detail.

Comment: I see. By the way, do you think it is a good idea that putting the word "*over* $\star$" whenever talking about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors?